# Java 8 stream и разбор HTML

Tags: java, html, jsoup, java-stream

Возникла такая ситуация, распарсиваю HTML при помощи jsoup (1.7.3), метод `isUse` принимает `Element` и возвращает подходит ли он для дальнейшей работы (есть куча тегов `<article>`). Пишу на Java 8 и подумал заюзать фишечки новые:

```
List<Element> news = items.stream().filter(e -> isUse(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Все работает, вопросов этот код не вызывает, но я подумал сравнить с обычным циклом:

```
List<Element> news = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element e : items) 
    if (isPodcast(e))
        news.add(e);
```

И получается, что 2 вариант примерно в 2 - 1.5 раза всегда работает быстрее. Версия java:

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

ОС: mac os x 10.9.3. Пробовал на Windows 7 x64 с java8u5.

P.S. Не то, чтобы меня как то напрягало сильно разница в 60 - 80 мс, просто интересно почему именно так.

Comment: Извините, но таки почему вы в одном случае используете `isUse()` а в другом `isDodcast()`? Не из-за этого ли меняется скорость?

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант и должен быть быстрей в теории, за счет меньшего кол-ва вызовов методов, но точно не в 1.5-2 раза. Как сравнивали производительность? В 99.99999% случаев неверна методика сравнения.

Comment: вполне возможно, что не так мерию. 
просто перед и после цикла/stream-а вызываю System.currentTimeMillis() и вывожу разность.

Comment: @KoCaTKo вы попали в эти 99.99999% :) начнтие отсюда и по ключевым словам http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p4vL6EhzOk Но, как минимум, ваш вариант статистически незначим, в силу выполнения всего одного повторения.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку )

Answer (score 1):

Первое обращение к Stream API в программе всегда очень медленно, потому что надо:

- Загрузить много вспомогательных классов Stream API
- Через LambdaMetafactory сгенерировать много анонимных классов из lambda-выражений, которые там используются.
- Если до этого и лямбды не использовались, загрузить классы ASM, которые используются для генерации анонимных классов.
- Всё это добро JIT-компилировать.

Это всё делается один раз и занимает может около 50 мс. Повторные обращения к Stream API гораздо быстрее. Попробуйте повторить тест несколько раз.